# "Meet the Pros" -- Scheduled chat #1 with Jonathan Williamson

Tags: discussion, scheduled-chat

Yesterday, I emailed [Jonathan Williamson](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/44/jonathan-williamson), one of the founders of Blender Cookie, and we're planning on hosting a scheduled chat right here on Blender.SE. The chat will be some sort of interview with professional Blender users/developers, where we can ask him questions about his history with Blender, other CG tools, personal life, etc.

We're thinking about doing it this next Thursday, June 6, 2013. I'm just not sure what time will work best for everyone, since we're in multiple time zones. Comment below stating which time you think would work best for the community (in CST, please).

> ### Friday, June 7th at 2:00 UTC
>
> (or **Thursday, June 6th at 7:00pm PST**)
>
> It should last an hour or more.

Sign up [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8923/meet-the-pros?tab=schedule). The room is currently set to gallery, but will be open when the event starts.

---

## This event has ended. You can find the transcript [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8923/conversation/jonathan-williamson).

Comment: Thanks for the invitation @Dan-the-man!

I'm on the West Coast but have a pretty flexible schedule. I can make most any time of day work.

Comment: I've noticed that the times people have been most active on the site (at least during the private beta) are about 8:00AM, 3:00PM, 8:00PM, and 1:00AM West Coast time. 8:00PM probably sees slightly more traffic than those other times, but it's variable.

Comment: @JonathanWilliamson No problem! I think this will be interesting.

Comment: Ping me once you have a time decided on - I'll add the event to the Community Bulletin sidebar.

Comment: @Shog9 Alright! Cool.

Comment: Times in UTC would even be more useful. I have no clue what CST means :O Well, now I do, but it is a timezone format I never ever use. UTC sounds more open towards the entire world :)

Comment: @Shog9 We have a little problem. Since we are doing this mainly to attract new users, and there is a 20 minimum rep required for chatting, new users won't be able to communicate. Is it possible to take off the minimum rep requirement for [this room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8923/meet-the-pros) only?

Comment: Not exactly, but there is a work-around - [you just need a moderator sitting in on your chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111942/allow-inviting-people-with-rep-20-to-private-chat/111946#111946).

Comment: @Shog9 Ok. We have decided a time.

Comment: Big fan of Jonathan Williamson, have followed his tuts for years. Unfortunately time doesn't work out for me, is it possible to get chat transcript for the session?

Comment: @PlastyGrove Yes. [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8923/meet-the-pros?tab=conversations) you will find a bookmarked transcript once the chat is over.

Comment: This is confusing people on main, since they don't know that the event has already passed. I propose posting all nominations here etc and creating another one for links to the transcripts and dates of those that have passed. (renamed it)

Comment: Ok @iKlsR. Good idea.