# "Meet the Pros" -- Scheduled chat #2 with Campbell Barton

Tags: discussion, scheduled-chat

In the same style as the previous interview with [Jonathan Williamson](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90/meet-the-pros-scheduled-chats), Campbell Barton ([ideasman_42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman_42)) has agreed to take some time out of his schedule for a similar session with us.

For those who don't know… Campbell is one of the lead developers of Blender and we're planning on hosting a scheduled chat right here on Blender.SE. The chat will be a sort of realtime interview where we can ask him questions about his history with Blender, other CG tools, current projects etc. *Be creative and come with your questions. :)*.

We're thinking about doing it this next week Saturday July 27th. We're not sure what time will work best for everyone since we're in different time zones and are still trying to get these events into a schedule. This can be adjusted slightly so comment below stating which time you think would work best for you *(in UTC, preferably)*.

> ### Saturday, July 27th at 15:00 UTC
>
> It should last an hour or thereabout.

You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8923/meet-the-pros?tab=schedule) *(optional but nice to let us know how many people plan to attend)*. The [room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8923/meet-the-pros) is currently set to Gallery *(closed)*, but will be open for everyone when the event starts.

---

## This event has ended. You can find the conversation [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8923/conversation/scheduled-chat-2-with-campbell-barton)

Comment: Awesome. This is going to be great.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm going to be out of town on the 27th.